# How do you change from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 in Nitro on MacOS

Tags: database, mysql, mariadb

I usually use Nitro and docker to run Craft.

Nitro created a Docker container with MySQL 5.7.  How can I change that version to MySQL 8?

Comment: Do you want to _add_ MySQL 8, so you're running both 5.7 and 8.0? Or do you want to replace MySQL 5.7 with MySQL 8.0?

Comment: Hi, I want to replace MySQL 5.7 with MySQL 8 in Nitro!

Comment: @BradBell, I'm looking to have 2 different versions for 2 different servers, what would be the method to add another MySQL server on another version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

1. From the terminal run `nitro stop`.
2. From Docker Desktop, click on Containers/Apps.
3. Find the MySQL 5.7 container and click the trash icon to remove it.
4. From the terminal, run `nitro edit`.
5. Under databases, you should see something like:

```
engine: mysql
version: "5.7"
port: "3306"
```

6. Change `"5.7"` to `"8.0"`.
7. Save the changes.
8. From the terminal, run `nitro apply`.

Comment: Yeah, actually that worked for me, thank you!!! First I backed up my DB, and I did that you wrote and it works perfectly. I owe you one!!